# Is there a way to import data from old MS Access database to New SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm new to sitecore. I have an requirement to Move data from old MS Access database to new site webform for marketers database(SQL server). How can this be achieved?

Any helpful Recomendations/Suggestions are appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking to move the the Data the Upsizing Wizard or the  [SQL Migration Assistant for Access](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/migration.aspx) (depends on the versions of the DB)  can do this pretty easily.

If you need to transform the data you can do it from Access using table links or you can do it via SQL Server using SQL Server IntegrationServices SSIS. Finally you could write a client program that does it if none of those other options are suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the data import / export wizard in SQL Server to import data from Access.